# CSS3 Transition rotate issue

Tags: css, rotation, transition

I am new to css3 transitions so the fix is probably easy for you. I am busy with a new website where i want to rotate some images. In a new html document it works, but when i try to implement it to my website it does nothing. www.jsfiddle.net/NXRvB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a negative `z-index` on `#circelwrap` which will prevent your `:hover` because you are moving the element behind its container.

```
#circelwrap {

    z-index: -1;
}
```

remove this and it works.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NXRvB/1/)

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Do you have any idea how I can get the circles behind the second section when I remove the z-index?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `behind the second section`. What is the second section? The "About" page?

Comment: I mean if i put the circelwrap on fixed, the circles have to get under the second section

Comment: the second section is the about page, i want the circles to scroll under it

Comment: Yep, that's what I want.

Comment: No worries. I'll take an upvote if there's one going